# Google карта при подключении перехватить $_GET

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps-api, get

Добрый день
Вот скрипт получения маркеров - он делает
**`downloadUrl("/maps.php", function(data) {`**
мне нужно в /maps.php перехватить мой $_GET параметр

```
   _this.fillUpWithMarkers = function() {
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  downloadUrl("/maps.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;

        var mark = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < mark.length; i++) {

          var name = mark[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = mark[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = mark[i].getAttribute("type");
          var photo = mark[i].getAttribute("photo");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(mark[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(mark[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>"+"<img src="+photo+" width=200 height=100><br/>" + address;

          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon.icon,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(mark[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(mark[i].getAttribute("lng")))
      });

            markers.push(marker);

            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
          }


        });

  };
```

maps.php

```
<?php

require("config.php");

// Start XML file, create parent node

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

$connection=mysql_connect ('kalashik.mysql.ukraine.com.ua', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());}

// Set the active MySQL database

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
if(!empty($_GET['serch'])){

$input = $_GET['serch']; 
$result = explode(",", $input);
$serch='';
if(count($result)>1){
foreach($result as $m){
    if($m!=$result[0]){
    $serch.=' AND type='.$m;
    }else{
    $serch.='type='.$m;  
    }}
}else{
    $serch.='type='.$result;
}    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE $serch";
}else{
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE id>0";
}
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("photo", $row['photo']);
}
```

уходит в `else` на `if(!empty($_GET[]))`

Comment: Инструменты разработчика в браузере откройте и посмотрите какие данные отсылаются на сервер в запросе к `map.php`, если не получается на сервере их увидеть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых я не вижу передачи гет параметра. Где вы передаете данные?

```
...
downloadUrl("/maps.php", function(data) {
...
```

Как минимум должно быть

```
...
downloadUrl("/maps.php?search=text", function(data) {
...
```

Во-вторых лучше проверять на наличие в массиве ключа и на значение

```
...
if(isset($_GET['serch']) && $_GET['serch'] !== '') {
...
```

И конечно не допускайте SQL инъекций. Используйте [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php) или хотя бы [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, как в downloadUrl передать апраметры

Comment: Добавил в ответ
/maps.php?search=text

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую.